# Different attempt at proof of $A_n$ does not have a proper subgroup of index $< n$ for all $n \geq 5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

My attempt at a proof.

Suppose $A_n$, for n $\geq 5$, has a proper subgroup $H$ and $[A_n:H] = m < n$. Kumbuka: $A_n$ is simple for all n $\geq$ 5 a fact that we gonna use later. Take left cosets on H to be $\{aH | a \in A_n\} = C$ a map $\phi : C \rightarrow S_2$ defined by $\phi(aH) = (12)$ if $a \neq (1)$ and$\phi((1)H) = (1)$ .

Checking that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Give $a, b, \in A_n$ we got $\phi(aHbH) = \phi(abH) = ab = \phi(aH)\phi(bH)$ and by definition $\phi((1)H) = (1)$.

Anyway since $A_n$ is simple $Ker(\phi) = A_n$ so $\phi(aH) = (1) \text{ } \forall \text{ } a \in A_n$ but $\phi((1)H) = (1)$ so we got $aH, (1)H, \in Ker(\phi)$ For sure then $aH = H \text{ } \forall \text{ } a\in A_n$ which implies that $A_n \subset H$ but also $H \subset A_n$ meaning $A_n = H$. This is a contradiction since we supposed that $H$ is a PROPER subset of $A_n$. This means our supposition is dead wrong and $A_n$ got no proper subset of index $m < n$ for $n \geq 5$.

Any feedback is welcome. I'm still sorta new to proof writing for algebra.

Comment: I don't think $\phi$ is well-defined. I suggest getting a homomorphism $\psi:A_n\to S_m$.

Comment: Ah yes, it definitely is not well defined. However, I'm having a hard time convincing myself that I can make a homomorphism from A_n $\rightarrow$ S_m

Comment: Ok so I'm seeing there's an "induced quotient" from $A_n \rightarrow S_2$ which maybe works because you can send the identity of $A_n$ to the identity in $S_2$ and every other element to $(12)$, is that about right? Maybe I don't need to make a specific map and can just say "$\phi: A_n \rightarrow S_m$ but for some reason that still makes me uncomfortable at this stage.

Comment: I have updated the proof to reflect your suggestion

Comment: Alright, I thought on it for a sec and it sounds like since the index of $H$ in $A_n$ is $m$ then the order of the group, $C$ of left cosets of $H$ is also $m$ and we gotta be able to find a subgroup of $S_m$ that $C$ are isomorphic too? Is that about right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that $C$ is a group since $H$ is not assumed to be normal. However, $A_n$ acts on $C$ which induces a homomorphism $A_n\to Sym(C)\cong S_m$. Of course, this is the start of the standard proof that $A_n$ has no subgroups of index $m<n$.

Comment: David Hill, what does "induces a homomorphism" mean. I see that a lot but have never seen it explained. Are you saying that $\phi$ is more like $\phi : A_n \rightarrow S_2$ where $\phi(a) = \psi(aH \in C) = x \in S_2$ where the map $\psi$ is from $C \rightarrow S_2$?